# Size of custom UIButton(hexagon) don't work on different Iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-graphics

I have 4 UIButtons:

```
   import UIKit

class HexagonButton: UIButton {



    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        print("screenheight:\(self.frame.width)")
        let polySize:CGFloat = self.frame.width // change this

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSaveGState(context)

        var t0 = CGContextGetCTM(context)
        t0 = CGAffineTransformInvert(t0)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, t0)

        //Begin drawing setup
        CGContextBeginPath(context)

        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)



        //Start drawing polygon
        let center = CGPointMake(polySize, polySize)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y + polySize)
        for i in 0..<6
        {
            let x = polySize * CGFloat(sinf(Float(i) * 2.0 * Float(M_PI) / 6))
            let y = polySize * CGFloat(cosf(Float(i) * 2.0 * Float(M_PI) / 6))
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x + x, center.y + y)

        }


        //Finish Drawing
        CGContextClosePath(context)

        CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents(UIColor.formen25().CGColor))

        CGContextDrawPath(context, CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke)
        CGContextFillPath(context)

        CGContextRestoreGState(context)


    }
}
```

In the storyboard I made the UIButtons width equal the height of his view with a multiplier = 0.2.

If I start the app on an Iphone 5 I get the following result:
[image: on iphon 5]

But on an Iphone 6s plus it looks like this
[image: on iphone 6s plus]

The height of the View where the buttons are placed are changed by the user. Even if I use a static size for the buttons they are wrong on the iphone 6s plus. Is this a mistake of my HexagonButton?

Maybe I have to place the buttons in a specific way? I added the both UIButtons in the middle in a stackview and centered(horizontal and vertically) the stackview in the view. Then I centered the other UIButtons and gave them a top-and bottomspace(-14) to the stackview. I made all buttons the same size.

EDIT:
If I give the button a backgroundcolor it looks like this:
[image: button with backgroundcolor]

Comment: Looks lie the drawing code is correct but the problem is in the auto layout settings

Comment: ok. Do you have a tip how I should place this buttons?:)

Comment: Easiest solution is put the buttons into a superview and don't use any sort of autolayout to position them. Position the superview only.

Comment: which kind of superview? I tried it with a stackview.